# Is this the correct way to read FFT of a audio file? (python + wav)

Tags: python, audio, fft, wav

The audio file is a 16bit mono PCM audio file with varying samplerates and length of 10-30ms.

```
import struct
from pydub import AudioSegment
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.fftpack

sound = AudioSegment.from_wav("3000hz.wav")

raw_data = sound.raw_data# needs to be mono
sample_rate = sound.frame_rate
sample_size = sound.sample_width
channels = sound.channels

fmt = "%ih" % sound.frame_count() * channels
amplitudes= struct.unpack(fmt, raw_data)
yVals = scipy.fftpack.fft(amplitudes)

plt.plot(abs(yVals[:(len(yVals)/2)-1]),'r')
plt.show()
```

The output with a 3000hz wav file(taken from an online sin wave generator) results in a decent looking FFT but spikes at 9000, not 3000. This off by a factor of 3 is consistent in other tests. Is this ok? And is the code correct?

Comment: At first sight, it looks OK. You could plot the 'amplitudes' to verify that reading the wav file is done correctly.

Comment: Oh and make sure you're interpreting the axes values correctly. If the samplerate = 1000 and the FFT spikes at 100, that does not mean the real frequency is at 100 Hz :-)

Comment: @HenkvanderLaak Thanks for the help, it seems to give me the real freq * sample length(in seconds) Is that an okay correlation to make?

Answer (score 1):

By calling `plt.plot()` with only an `y` array and no corresponding `x` array, it will use `0, 1, ..., N-1` as the `x` values. This is not what we actually want, we want the frequency on the x-axis.

Let's denote the `x` value you see in the plot right now by "bin index". Let the length of the array be `N` and the sampling frequency be `fs`. When calculating an FFT, the bin index `0` corresponds to a frequency of 0 Hz. The next bin index `1` corresponds to the frequency `fs / N` Hz. This is because the FFT will have `N` values and go from `0` Hz to `fs` Hz, so each step is `fs / N` Hz. The next bin thus corresponds to `2 * fs / N` Hz, and so on. And the last bin `N-1` is `(N-1)/N * fs` Hz, so almost `fs` Hz.

If we want to create a plot where you have amplitude spectrum vs. frequency, then we need to manually create a frequency vector which contains the real frequency for each bin index. Luckily, `scipy.fftpack` contains a function for that: [`fftfreq`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.fftpack.fftfreq.html):

```
freq = scipy.fftpack.fftfreq(n=N, d=1.0 / fs)
```

Then we can modify the call to `plt.plot()` to use `freq` as the `x` values instead of `0 ... N-1`:

```
plt.plot(freq, abs(yVals), 'r')
```

With that, the peak should be at the correct position.

If you only want to see a single-sided spectrum, then you can crop both `freq` and `yVals` like you already do in the code in the question.